# Как вырезать строки которые содержат слово из одного файла и сохранить в другой?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Как вырезать строки, которые содержат слово из одного файла, и сохранить в другой?
К примеру, есть текст со множеством строк. В этом тексте встречаются "Fgj f".
Мне нужно все строки, в которых встречается это слово, скопировать в другой файл.
Пример:

```
file.txt
разный текст, символы, цифры **Fgj f** дальше те**Fgj f**кст.
**Fgj f**разный текст, символы, цифры,  дальше текст.
разный текст,**Fgj f** символы, цифры, дальше текст.
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
cat file.txt | grep 'Fgj f' >> otherFile.txt
```

Comment: Спасибо. А зачем cat? Просто с кетом не получилось. А вот убравши кет вроде вышло))

Comment: ну выводим в стандартный выходной поток, потом фильтруем и потом собираем

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: Если ответ полностью удовлетворяет вас, то пометье ответ как правильный

Comment: Погуглите *Useless use of cat*.

Comment: @AndrewBystrov grep не нужен cat. **grep патерн файл | tee новый_файл** можно без чая если использовать в скриптах

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1 (sed).

```
sed -n '/Fgj f/p' source_file > dest_file
```

Вариант 2 (awk).

```
awk '$0 ~ /Fgj f/ {print}' source_file > dest_file
```

Вариант 3 (grep).

```
grep 'Fgj f' source_file > dest_file
```